# Перевести SQL-запрос в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, datagridview

Есть два `DataGridView`. В одном главные записи, во втором детали по нему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю так

```
list = model.Contracts
    .Include(c => c.ListSubjects)
    .ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;


Contracts item = list
    .Find(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value));
dataGridView2.DataSource = item.ListSubjects
    .ToList();
```

Тогда во втором `DataGridView` вижу только записи для нужного `Contracts`. Но там только числа. Как мне подтянуть `Title` от `Subjects` и показывать во втором `DataGridView` только его.

Другими словами, выполнять запрос:

```
SELECT s.Title 
FROM Contracts c, ListSubjects ls, Subjects s
WHERE c.ID = ls.ID_Contract AND s.ID = ls.ID_Subject
```

Comment: Ну у вас 2 варианта: join или nested include

Comment: @tym32167я не понимаю как это написать

Comment: [Entity Framework - Include Multiple Levels of Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10822656/312041), [Entity Framework Join 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21051612/312041)

Comment: @tym32167 он не видит никаких таблиц и свойств в .ThenInclude

Comment: SELECT * FROM  Subjects  Inner Join [Имя таблицы] on [ключевое поле из таблицы, к которой подключаем] = [Ключевому полю подключаемой таблицы]

Comment: @Dude36 мне нужен LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var  title = (from cont in model.Contracts
             join lsSub in model.ListSubjects  on lsSub.Id_Contract equals cont.Id 
             join subj in model.Subjects on  subj.ID  equals lsSub.ID_Subject
             where cont.ID == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value))
             select subj.Title
             );
```

Как-то так. Если что-то не так - просьба сильно не пинать так, как написано было на коленке.

Comment: Не проходит. У вас фигурная скобка закрывает, но не открывает. И на все переменные ругается.

Comment: Исправил. Там фигурной скобки не должно быть

Comment: переменные исправьте согласно Вашему контексту.  Я взял название переменных с картинки сверху. Как вариант можете выложить ваш проект на просторы интернета. Я тогда смогу исправить название переменных согласно Вашему проекту. Если у Вас есть TeamViewer можем устроить сессию

Comment: Когда я получаю `Contracts` от выделения в `GridView`, как мне из него дойти до `Title` от `Subjects`? `Contracts item = list.Find(c => c.Id == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value));` В любом случае нужно using model?

Comment: Когда я делаю ваш запрос в событии изменения выделения первого Grid и ставлю var title как источник для второго - в первом отображается только одна строка, а во втором пусто. Будто оба источника переписываются.

Comment: teamviewer есть?

Comment: я разобрался в этом вопросе. Скорее даже успешно перебрал все варианты и узнал про баг VS, который не исправили с бородатых лет.